# No element "avfvideosrc" in GStreamer

Tags: macos, video-streaming, homebrew, gstreamer, video-capture

I'm trying to capture the internal camera of Mac using GStreamer, and I'm having trouble on my first steps.
I've installed GStreamer as well as the good, bad, base plugins using homebrew.

The `brew list` command shows `gstreamer`, `gst-plugins-bad`, `gst-plugins-good`, and `gst-plugins-base`.
However, when I try running the `gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc ! autovideosink`, I get the following error.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc ! autovideosink
(gst-plugin-scanner:45357): GStreamer-WARNING **: 19:27:36.232: Failed to load plugin '/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsrt.dylib': dlopen(/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsrt.dylib, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/srt/lib/libsrt.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsrt.dylib
  Reason: image not found
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "avfvideosrc"
```

Apparently something Hase gone wrong on install but I have no clue on how to fix it.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you use macOS Mojave or higher.

Comment: Actually I was trying it with High Sierra.  I'll try with my Mac with Mojave